# Error compiling Vue.js single-file component with scss block using custom webpack config

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I'm encountering an error while trying to setup scss in a vue project using single-file components. I currently encounter this error when I try to use a `<style lang="scss">` block, but otherwise my project works as expected.

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

<template>
^
      Invalid operator in attribute selector for object
      in C:\Users\yanch\OneDrive\Desktop\virtualenvs\agg_site\client\src\App.vue (line 1, column 2)
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& (./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&) 4:14-279
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/main.js
```

I'm not an expert but this error makes me think that there is an issue with my vue-loader rules. It seems like it's trying to compile the template as a style block (though I could be wrong). This is my webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader'},
            { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader'},
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']},
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, use: 'file-loader' },
            { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['vue-style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']},
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    ],  
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
          '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/style'),
        }
    },
};
```

And I have these packages installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
```

I followed the vue-loader setup instructions and I believe I have all the necessary loaders installed along with the proper rules, so I'm unsure why I'm getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit - Added App.vue below:

```
<template>
    <div id="app-container">
        <NavBanner class="nav-banner"/>
        <ProfileBanner/>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ProfileBanner from '@/components/ProfileBanner.vue';
    import NavBanner from '@/components/NavBanner.vue';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                message: 'Welcome to Leddit',

            };
        },
        components: {
            ProfileBanner,
            NavBanner,
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app-container {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-banner {
    height: 10%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please post app.vue.

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong. It looks like what I use. Perhaps this can help you like it helped me: https://itnext.io/vue-js-and-webpack-4-from-scratch-part-3-3f68d2a3c127 (see parts 1 and 2)

Comment: I added App.vue. And thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Comment: Update: I came back to the project today and compiled it successfully. I didn't make any changes. I'm going to delete the question unless anyone objects since it seems like not a real issue and probably just some mistake on my part. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: If you work out what the mistake was (and it's not something trivial like a typo) you could always post a self answer in case someone else has a similar issue.